# How to make a post request to paste data on a webpage field

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, http-post

I'm trying to find a way to paste some trades (which I've already correctly formatted) in a field box on this Online UK Capital Gains Tax Calculator - http://www.cgtcalculator.com/calculator.aspx - and then click on the 'Calculate' button to finally receive the information in the results box.

An example of some trades (not my trades) - this data is currently in a DataFrame:

```
B   01/12/2000  BARC    3000    4.82    15.00   72.3
B   02/12/2000  BARC    5000    4.825   15.00   120.62
B   03/09/2002  VOD    18000    3.04    10.00   273.60
B   15/01/2003  BP.     5000    3.75    10.00   93.75
B   24/03/2003  BP.     3000    3.82    10.00   57.30
S   14/04/2003  BARC    6000    5.52    15.00   0.00
S   23/02/2004  VOD     9000    3.62    10.00   0.00
S   24/02/2004  VOD     9000    3.625   10.00   0.00
S   15/07/2005  BP.     8000    6.28    10.00   0.00
B   22/01/2007  BP.     5000    5.50    10.00   124.20
B   22/06/2009  BP.     2000    5.02    10.00   50.20
S   24/12/2012  BP.     5000    4.336   10.00   0.00
```

When I paste the data above in the entry field and the click on 'Format/Sort', I can see it appearing on the html source as such:

```
<textarea name="TEXTAREA1" id="TEXTAREA1" class="trades" cols="114"> 
"Trade Data Appears Here"
```

Then, when I click on the 'Calculate' button, there appears to be a number of `<span>` tags flashing. The results can be seen under the `Network` and then `Response` tabs.

What would be the best way of pasting the trades data onto the webpage field, clicking on the Calculate button and then obtaining the results in Python? Would a `post.request` work? I'm just after some guidance here as I'm new to Python but understand that what I'm asking for might not be possible or even slightly too complex for me.

I've tried the following but I'm only getting the content of the webpage back.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("/Users/Test.csv")

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'http://www.cgtcalculator.com/calculator.aspx'
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: You either need to `post` to the address that `calculator.aspx` send the same info to, or you want to use UI manipulation package, e.g. Selenium to paste data and click the button for you.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for the reply. Before I get started with Selenium, do you think what I'm trying to do is actually possible?

Comment: With Selenium, sure, you're just automating UI interaction, unless the website has some sort of human identification, e.g. CAPCHA. With `requests.post` you might need to pass correct header/authorization data.

Comment: @QuangHoang That's great thanks, yes I don't think `requests.post` will work so I'll give Selenium a go!